# Apply recaptcha theme to tank auth

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha, tankauth

Tank auth recaptcha does not come with default. How can I apply recaptcha theme/custom theme to tank auth recaptcha?

Tried adding following in page's `<head>` tag but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'red'
 };
 </script>
```

Tried changing `auth.php`'s `_create_recaptcha()` method like this.

```
$options = "<script>var RecaptchaOptions = {theme: 'red', custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'};</script>\n";
```

Then I got[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right path, next thing you have to do is that remove explicit call for recaptcha components from the view . Then it will work as expected